Need advice on the hero section of my website
I'm looking for some advice on the hero section of my website. My company specializes in making iron-forged street lamps, and I'm working on refining the main visual section that first grabs visitors' attention. The challenge I'm facing is that I only have photos of the lamps either with a transparent background or installed on posts in park settings.
Here's an example of what I've put together so far (please ignore the logo on the left—I'll be updating that). I'm aiming for a look that really captures the craftsmanship and elegance of these lamps, but I feel like something's missing, and I'm not sure how to tie it all together.
If anyone has any suggestions, advice, or even some inspiration that could help enhance this section, I'd greatly appreciate it! Would love to completely redesign it and change the image if needed (add more lamps e.t.c.)
Here’s the link to the site so you can see the design system I’m working with: https://luxiron.si/home-2/


Welcome Patrik! Unfortunately, design consultations aren't really what this site is about. In addition, "idea farming" is off topic. You should hire a designer if you want a direct consultation regarding your business designs.

If you edit your post to follow our critique requirements we might could keep this question open

When coming up with ideas, consider that the vast majority of your users will probably be using a vertically-oriented mobile device. You might need two options and a media query
